# generalizability of training model to testing set

Tags: r, machine-learning, train-test-split

Let's say `mtcars` contain 3 independent datasets: `cyl=4`, `cyl=6` and `cyl=8`.

I'd like to use two of the groups as my training set, and cyl=4 as the testing set. The aim is to check how well my model performs on the test data:

```
training <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl!=4,]
testing <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl==4,]
```

Model:

```
m <- lm(mpg ~ disp + wt, data=training)

pred.test <- predict(m, testing)
mean.err <- mean((pred.test - testing$mpg)^2)
```

But what does that tell me about generalizability? How can I determine if `mean.err` (or any other value) is a reasonable number? Or is what I'm doing in the example above not the way to test generalizability?

Comment: "How can I determine if mean.err (or any other value) is a reasonable number?" People will often compare it to the mean squared error on the training set, and see how much bigger it is. "Or is what I'm doing in the example above not the way to test generalizability?" Note that what you're doing is harder than what people usually mean when they say "Out of Sample" or "Test" error, since you're extrapolating outside of your training domain (which has no cyl=4).

Comment: This seems to *require* domain knowledge, because you are asking how accurately you need to predict `mpg`.  It depends on your application -- not on any statistical theory.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMadden. The mse in my training set is 7.71. But how can I test if the difference between the mse of the training model is meaningfully larger than that of mean.err?

Comment: @whuber, thanks! Yes, I know this likely depends on the application. At this stage, I'm just trying to understand (using simple examples like in my question) what kind of tools are available that would allow me to answer the question of model generalizability.

Comment: for example, comparing mse as @JohnMadden suggested would be one way, although I'd still need to somehow meaningfully compare/interpret the mses. I'm not sure about the utility of cross validation and related techniques in my case...

Comment: @locus there's nothing stopping us theoretically from using a formal hypothesis test to establish a difference between the two MSEs, but for cultural reasons this is quite rare and I'm not sure I can think of any software for this. A good place to start might be to create bootstrapped estimates of in and Oo sample MSE and compare them with a boxplot. But I do have to second whuber's point: typically we will use our domain knowledge to establish whether the change in accuracy is practically important rather than using a formal statistical procedure, especially because...

Comment: ...there's not much knowledge to be gained: we *know* generalization is a nonzero amount harder than in-sample prediction, the question is whether that difference is of practical significance.